# Android: error inflating class xml, application crashed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using a custom view class of MyGauge with a custom class import of RadialGauge. Below is my class code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.FileFormat;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.GaugeFont;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.GaugeFontSize;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.LayoutTarget;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.Needle;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.NeedleStyle;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.RadialBorderStyle;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.RadialCapStyle;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.RadialGauge;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.RangeType;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.Section;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.TickmarkStyle;
import com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.Title;
public class MyGauge extends View 
{

RadialGauge gauge;

public MyGauge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}


public MyGauge(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyGauge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}



public void init()
{
gauge = new RadialGauge();

//gauge.setBackColor = java.awt.Color.white;
gauge.getBorder().setColor(new java.awt.Color(230, 232, 250));  // Color Silver
Log.d("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", "iiiiiiiiiiiii"+gauge);
gauge.getBorder().setGlare(true);
gauge.getBorder().setInsideColor(java.awt.Color.black) ;
gauge.getBorder().setStyle(RadialBorderStyle.getSemiCircularBorder07());
gauge.getBorder().setGlare(false);

//Setting the MainScale
gauge.getMainScale().setMax(300);

//Setting first Section
Section section1 = new Section();
section1.setMin(210);
section1.setMax(270);
section1.getBar().setColor(Color.yellow);
section1.getTickmarks().setColor(Color.white);
gauge.getMainScale().getSections().add(section1);

//Setting second Section
section1 = new Section();
section1.setMin(270);
section1.setMax(300);
section1.getBar().setColor(Color.red);
section1.getTickmarks().setColor(Color.white);
gauge.getMainScale().getSections().add(section1);

gauge.getMainScale().getBar().setVisible(false);

gauge.getMainScale().getCap().setStyle(RadialCapStyle.getRotatingCap02());
gauge.getMainScale().getCap().setColor(Color.darkGray);

Needle needle1 =(Needle) gauge.getMainIndicator();
needle1.setStyle(NeedleStyle.getNeedle10());
needle1.setUseRangeColor(RangeType.SECTION);
needle1.setValue("240");

gauge.getMainScale().getTickmarks().getMajor().setColor(Color.darkGray);
gauge.getMainScale().getTickmarks().getMajor().getLabel().setFont(new GaugeFont("Tahoma", GaugeFontSize.SMALLER, java.awt.Font.BOLD));
gauge.getMainScale().getTickmarks().getMajor().getLabel().setColor(Color.white);
gauge.getMainScale().getTickmarks().getMajor().setStep(30);
gauge.getMainScale().getTickmarks().getMajor().setStyle(TickmarkStyle.getTickmark01_2());
gauge.getMainScale().getTickmarks().getMedium().setColor(new java.awt.Color(230, 232, 250));  // Color Silver
gauge.getMainScale().getTickmarks().getMinor().setColor(Color.gray);

//Setting the titles:

Title title1 = new Title();
title1.setText("PSI");
title1.setColor(new java.awt.Color(211, 211, 211));  // Color LightGray
title1.setFont(new GaugeFont("Tahoma", GaugeFontSize.SMALLER, java.awt.Font.BOLD));
title1.getLayout().setTarget(LayoutTarget.ANCHOR_POINT);
title1.getLayout().getAnchorPoint().setLocation(0,0.225);
gauge.getTitles().add(title1);

gauge.setWidth(320);
gauge.setHeight(350);
gauge.setToolTipEnabled(false);
gauge.renderControl();
try {
    gauge.exportGauge(FileFormat.XML, "file:///assets/image.bmp");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", "nnnnnnnnn"+gauge);
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

And custom view code in XML file is as follows:

```
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/gauge"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_below="@id/valrow2">

   <view class="com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge"
       android:id="@+id/gview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I am getting error as "Error inflating class com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge" in xml with App crashed. Can anyone please help why is this happening..

EDIT: Below is the Logcat:

```
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.gaugesystems/com.example.gaugesystems.MyViewStatus}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #128: Error inflating class com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #128: Error inflating class com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1916)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at com.example.gaugesystems.MyViewStatus.onCreate(MyViewStatus.java:21)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    ... 11 more
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    ... 23 more
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at com.softwarefx.chartfx.gauge.RadialGauge.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge.init(MyGauge.java:55)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge.<init>(MyGauge.java:36)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    ... 26 more
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at ChartFX.internal.WebForms.Gauge.BaseGauge.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    ... 29 more
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Color
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    at SfxNETGauges.System.Drawing.Color.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
01-15 12:32:56.515: E/AndroidRuntime(14795):    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat trace.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks suspicious:

```
   <view class="com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge"
```

When I have used custom view objects, I use the following syntax:

```
   <com.example.gaugesystems.MyGauge ...>
```

Not sure if that is the problem, but it should be quick to try.

Comment: Both are alternative ways to specify a custom view in the layout.

Comment: How can i add inflator in the java class, if it helps??

Answer (score 0):

According to logcat it seems that `ChartFX.internal.WebForms.Gauge.BaseGauge` tries to create a static instance of `java.awt.Color`, but JVM cannot load the latter, so it throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

**EDIT**:
Looks like Software FX has its library ported to Android: http://www.softwarefx.com/mobile/pgm/clients/android.aspx. I think you should use this one.
On the other hand, you can switch to an open-source gauge library, for instance, http://android.codeandmagic.org/2012/08/android-gaugeview-library/.

Comment: i have added jre libraries through java build path, then why still it is not able to find that..? And moreover i am not getting ay error while compling my code..

Comment: You can try and find `java.awt.Color` in `classes` folder, and it seems to me that the class doesn't exist there. Moreover, I think it's impossible to use AWT in an Android project. Try to look for some ports, maybe they'll help you. Here's one for example: https://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/

Comment: Yes, i too thought that its not possible to use AWT in Android but i just tried once to face it.. Thanks Michael